# Can i use DC Brushed motors for building a drone?

Tags: quadcopter, motor, brushless-motor

I want to make a drone. But my budget is very low. Brushless motors are very expensive. I want use the Brushed CHEAP ones. can i us them ?

Comment: Certainly you can, though brushless "outrunner" motors can be found for less than \$10 each, and they are considerably more powerful and efficient (a set of 4 small brushed motors can be as low as \$10 for the set, at least in the US). That can lower your battery costs, depending on how long you want it to fly. But if you've already determined that brushed are required for price reasons, stick with that decision. They'll fly.

Comment: You should factor in lifespan into your cost calculations.I have a syma x5c with small brushed motors.They burn out so quickly that its not even funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cheap small multirotors use use brushed motors.

Some examples:

- http://www.banggood.com/Cheerson-CX10-CX10-Mini-24G-4CH-6-Axis-LED-RC-Quadcopter-RTF-p-926614.html
- http://www.banggood.com/Eachine-H8-Mini-Headless-Mode-2_4G-4CH-6-Axis-RC-Quadcopter-RTF-p-975808.html

The drawback with brushed motors is that they are much less efficient and can produce less torque. Thus, they have to run at a much higher RPM in order to produce sufficient power.
I think you will find that it will be harder to manage crisp control of your multirotor with brushed motors.

Comment: If you look up the specs for the Nano brushed motors you will see they have a nominal 5 hour life. https://micro-motor-warehouse.com/collections/all-motors/products/cl-0615-14 >> lifetime rating 5-6 hours. Cheap costs more in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely look at a brushed motor when the budget is low. They have a reputation of being less powerful, but the main problem is they have a very high RPM. This means you either have to use very small inefficient propellers or a geared system. Brushed geared mini-drones have pretty good performance when it comes to battery life because the propeller is big compared to the weight. Small, coreless brushed motors are pretty efficient but wear out after some time.